# How to get time in GMT?

Tags: python, time, timezone, localtime, abbreviation

So far I have:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z", time.localtime())
'Tue, 10 Sep 2013 22:55:08 Mitteleurop\xe4ische Sommerzeit'
```

But what I need is:

```
'Tue, 10 Sep 2013 22:55:08 GMT'
```

Comment: I assume that the fact that the time doesn't change is an oversight? The time at GMT is currently 2 hours behind the time in Germany.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import time
>>> time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT", time.gmtime())
'Tue, 10 Sep 2013 20:08:51 GMT
```